# (Topology) To show inverse f is continuous.

Tags: general-topology

I know that for $X,\; Y$
  topological spaces

A map $f\,:\, X\rightarrow Y$
  is continuous iff for any open $u$
  in $Y$
 , $f^{-1}\left(u\right)$
  is open in $X$
 .

Then, to show $f^{-1}\,:\, Y\rightarrow X$
  is continuous,

can I say that for any open $u$
  in $X$
 , $f(u)$
  is open in $Y$
  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if $f$ is not bijective, then there is no function $f^{-1}: Y \to X$. So you need to assume this about $f$ to make any sense of your question. (There is always a map $f^{-1}: \mathcal{P}(Y) \to \mathcal{P}(X)$ which returns the inverse image of a subset of $Y$, but this is different from a map $f^{-1}: Y \to X$ inverting $f$; the notation is very confusing but is standard.)

Once you know that $f$ is bijective, then it's true that checking whether $f^{-1}$ is continuous is the same as checking that $f$ takes open sets to open sets, since $(f^{-1})^{-1}(U) = U$.

Note that $f$ being bijective and continuous does not imply that $f^{-1}$ is continuous; there are plenty of counterexamples, so this is something that has to be checked for each individual $f$.

Comment: Thank you. I'm confusing between inverse function and preimage.. f is bijective implies $\left(f^{-1}\right)^{-1}\left(U\right)=U$, in this case as a function, right?

Comment: @ChunSom yeah. If $f$ is bijective, then there is a function which is usually called $f^{-1}$, let's call it $g$, such that $fg = \text{Id}$. Now, to say $g$ is continuous is to say that $g^{-1}(U)$ is open whenever $U$ is an open set in $X$. By thinking about the definition, you should agree that $g^{-1}(U) = f(U)$ (you might want to write out a formal proof).